# How to get enabled print Services in Android 7.0

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to get the enabled print services in Android.
Below code works fine in upto Android 6.0. But it is not working in Android 7.0

```
    String enabledPrintServices = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), "enabled_print_services");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Nougat and up, for some reason you have to use `"disabled_print_services"` instead of `"enabled_print_services"` to get a list of disabled print services.
[Documentation in source code is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43811512/how-to-get-enabled-print-services-in-android-7-0).

If all you need is to see if your print service is enabled or disabled, then this alternative would be equally effective. Otherwise, if your wish is to list all enabled print services, then I have not found any such code that works for Android 7.0 and up.